# Reason for giving owner less permissions than group

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, administration

I have found this example in book.
Is there any reason to give user less permissions than the group ?

Example:

```
# ll /home/lab/team1
dr-xrwx--x 3 thomas team1 4096 Nov 24 12:46 exercise1
# ll /home/lab/team1/exercise1
dr-xrwx--- 2 marcus team1 4096 Nov 24 12:46 results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. If you have a list of birthday presents for Marcus, let every user except Marcus read (and write) it. Note that the group rights won’t give him access, since the user rights are more specific.

Obviously, this is more useful with group vs. other, since it is kind of difficult to stop Marcus from giving himself read access. But it could be done on a system having the necessary ACL technology. I don’t know if those exist.